Make object method accept parameter with access to other methods (and their arguments) of the object
I've tried to make this work in typescript without success. I have a function or type function that I want to pass in an object of methods into and make the first argument of each method accept an event object that has access to other methods in the object. This event object should be able to access the other methods and their arguments but without that first event argument. It's better shown with code so please see the example below. This is a pared down version of what I'm trying to do so that only the salient parts are there to demonstrate the problem:
type Status = 'initial' | 'sign_in' | 'error'

declare function getHandlers<
    const Handlers extends {
        [status in Status]:  (
            ev: {
                status: status,
                to: {
                    [to_status in Exclude<Status, status>]: 
                        Handlers[to_status] extends (ev: any, ...args: infer Args) => infer Return_Type
                        ? (...args: Args) => Return_Type
                        : never
                }
            },
            ...args: any[]
        ) => any
    },
>( handlers: Handlers ): Handlers

const handlers = getHandlers({
    initial(ev) {
        ev.to.error
    },
    sign_in(ev, si1: string) { return 'hi' },
    error(ev, e1: number, e2: boolean) { return 22 },
})

handlers.initial
handlers.error
handlers.sign_in

In the example, ev of initial(ev) gets typed as:
ev: {
    status: "initial";
    to: {
        sign_in: (...args: any[]) => any;
        error: (...args: any[]) => any;
    };
}

I'd like it to be cast to:
ev: {
    status: "initial";
    to: {
        sign_in: (si1: string) => "hi";
        error: (e1: number, e2: boolean) => 22;
    };
}

As far as I can tell I'm running into a recursion issue / existential types where typescript cannot infer the other methods and ev being any  breaks the traversal. Maybe
I've tried using various tricks like NoInfer, T & {}, etc. I've scoured stack overflow for similar issues and found a few but they are either unanswered or different enough from what I'm trying that I get lost trying to apply the same workarounds
Here is an example of the same code where I'm trying to delay the inference a bit, the main addition is a Type parameter Parsed_Handlers

type Status = 'initial' | 'sign_in' | 'error'

declare function getHandlers<
    const Handlers extends {
        [status in Status]:  any
    },
    const Parsed_Handlers = {
        [status in Status]: (
            ev: {
                status: status,
                to: {
                    [to_status in Exclude<keyof Handlers, status>]: 
                        Handlers[to_status] extends (ev: any, ...args: infer Args) => infer Return_Type
                        ? (...args: Args) => Return_Type
                        : never
                }
            },
            ...args: any[]
        ) => any
    },
>( handlers: Handlers ): Parsed_Handlers

const handlers = getHandlers({
    initial(ev) {
        ev.to.error
    },
    sign_in(ev, si1: string) { return 'hi' },
    error(ev, e1: number, e2: boolean) { return 22 },
})

handlers.initial
handlers.error
handlers.sign_in

Notice I'm returning Parsed_Handlers as the return type. This is exactly typed how I would like, for instance handlers.initial becomes:
initial: (ev: {
    status: "initial";
    to: {
        sign_in: (si1: string) => "hi";
        error: (e1: number, e2: boolean) => 22;
    };
}, ...args: any[]) => any

Perfect as opposed to the previous example where handlers.initial is:
initial: (ev: {
    status: "initial";
    to: {
        sign_in: never;
        error: never;
    };
}, ...args: any[]) => any

If in the 2nd example I try to change handlers: Handlers to handlers: Parsed_Handlers then it breaks down again and handlers.initial and the ev parameter of the intial method gets cast to:
initial(ev: {
    status: "initial";
    to: {
        sign_in: (...args: unknown[]) => unknown;
        error: (...args: unknown[]) => unknown;
    };
}): void

So in conclusion, the question is how can I get things typed how I'd like as in the 2nd example but applied to the methods passed in? Please help! Thanks in advance
Example 1:
https://tsplay.dev/mpkOxN
Example 2:
https://tsplay.dev/m3GjEm
